# How to compile all dependencies and shared libs into one binary

Tags: c++, tesseract

I want to compile all dependencies etc and shared libraries into the binary?

How to do that?

```
g++ -std=c++11 txtocr.cpp -o txtocr -llept -ltesseract
```

Tesseract depends on `leptonica` and some shared `tesseract` libraries.. But how to compile everything into the binary so it would be 100% portable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert shared library to static library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302954/convert-shared-library-to-static-library)

Comment: No, I want to compile everything into one binary

Comment: @clarkk That's what static libraries do :) .

Comment: As the answer(s) in the duplicate say: If you only have a shared library you will need to source of it to build a static library and then link with the static library.

Comment: @TartanLlama Not really. Static libraries are nothing more than collections of object files. If you want to have a static library without any dependencies you have to extract the object files from the shared libraries, which is not possible (since a shared library is more like an executable file).

Comment: For the OP: What you seem to be wanting is static *linking*, so the executable program doesn't depend on any shared libraries. Try adding the linker flag `-static`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the answer is "**It depends**". **If you only have the shared library without the code of the library** I am afraid the answer will be **NO** as not all information you need in order to build a static application are within your dynamic library.