# Using Dynamic Libraries in a non-linux environment

Tags: iar, imx6

I'm using a non-linux OS (call it RTOS) on an iMX6 Quad processor (IAR IDE). I would like to use the onboard GC320 GPU to do some 2D bitblit, clearing and other functions. The library that NXP provides is libg2d.so which is a dynamic lib from Vivante and is proprietary. Is there any way to easily use this library in my environment? What I would like to get is the library in static form form that I can just link to; anyone know if that is available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert shared library to static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302954/convert-shared-library-to-static-library)

Comment: Since the library is proprietary to Vivante, I don't get any source code - can't rebuild it. Assuming the library is position independent code, and doesn't depend on anything outside of itself (I know it needs a memory allocator), then if I had the location of function entry points I could use it.