# Shared and static library linkage

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I have 3 libraries liba.so, libb.so and libc.so

Liba.so and Libb.so are using libc.so.

In my application I use openssl 1.0.1, and libc.so is using an old version of openssl 0.9.8

To avoid the following warning :

```
libssl.so.0.9.8 needed by XXX libc.so may conflict with libssl.so.1.0.1
```

Could I use libc as static library?

Can liba.so and libb.so still correctly working if I use libc.a ?

Comment: Both of those versions of OpenSSL are pretty old.  Who is the supplier of `libc`, can you get it updated?

Comment: No it's not possible because I do not have the source code.

Comment: Hmmm.  No vendor you can contact then?  Without that, you [seem to be out of luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302954/convert-shared-library-to-static-library).  Any chance you can use (old, buggy, insecure) openssl 0.9.8 in your app?

Comment: There is no solution for this issue?